# After migrating Umbraco web from IIS 7.5 to 8.5 member login not working on Firefox (only) - Forms auth cookie not set

Tags: firefox, iis-7.5, iis-8, umbraco7

Two 100% identical Umbraco 7.5.2 webs are running on a Windows 2008R2 server with IIS 7.5 and a Windows 2012 server with IIS 8.5. Version .NET is 4.5.2.

Member login using method this.Members.Login in Umbraco SurfaceController works in all browsers - just in **Firefox 64 it only works in IIS 7.5**. **Members.Login seems to return true but no Forms authentication cookie is set.**

We tested 32bit vs 64bit, various random IIS settings - everything is set identically. No idea - we are going crazy.

Our guess it might have something to do with FF Cookie handling on POST with a 302 redirect afterwards. But here, too, browser dev tools show identical stuff.

***Any idea*** about any ***applicable*** differences regarding Firefox/IIS 7.5-8.5/POST/redirect is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** it is a cookie issue - in some Firefoxes the ASP.NET MVC authentication cookie is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was stupid, but I put this here in case somebody has a similar experience.

The server was set one hour too early, and Firefox 64 doesn't allow Cookies that are set with a time like that. All other browsers do.